# flutter: set font of SnackbarAction label

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to set the font of a SnackBarAction in flutter? It seems to use the default system font.

```
SnackBarAction(
                label: 'my text', // how to sent font?
                onPressed: () {},
              )
```

Comment: change your snack_bar.dart File inside       
// add this code                                


=====>  return FlatButton(
      onPressed: _haveTriggeredAction ? null : _handlePressed,
      child: Text(widget.label,style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: "YOUR_FONT",
      ),),
      textColor: textColor,
      disabledTextColor: disabledTextColor,
    );

Comment: @Robin Manoli Please check my updated answer!

Comment: @JayGadariya where do you find this file?

Comment: wait i will post answer

Comment: @JayGadariya You must not change anything inside `snack_bar.dart`, as It is an internal class in flutter sdk and if your forcefully do those changes would reflect on your all projects, which I think would be a disaster.

Answer (score 4):

you can define custom theme for snackbar globally in ThemeData:

```dart
runApp(MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      snackBarTheme: SnackBarThemeData(contentTextStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: "customfontName")
    ),
),
```

to change font of action button inside Snack bar you can define font for text of button itself:

```dart
SnackBar(
   content: Row(
      children: [
          Expanded(child: Text('Some Text')),
          TextButton(
            child: Text('Action', 
               style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Your Font')),
               ),
             ],
          ),     
        ),
```

Comment: This changes the snackbar content but doesn't seem to affect the "action" button.

Comment: @mgalgs Answer updated

Answer (score 1):

Declare a common `snackBarTheme` inside `ThemeData` which you might have inside your main.dart,

```
 runApp(MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      snackBarTheme: SnackBarThemeData(contentTextStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: "montserrat")),
    ),
...
```

Do not forget to `restart` app completely to test the solution.

Comment: change your snack_bar.dart File inside       
// add this code                                


=====>  return FlatButton(
      onPressed: _haveTriggeredAction ? null : _handlePressed,
      child: Text(widget.label,style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: "YOUR_FONT",
      ),),
      textColor: textColor,
      disabledTextColor: disabledTextColor,
    );

Comment: snackbar content textstyle also change style of snackbaraction label style??

Comment: perhaps this answer would set the font on the snackbar but not snackbar action? perhaps you have to set the default font for flatbutton? do you know how to do that?

Comment: you have to do change in your snackbar default file which provided by flutter see my first comment

Comment: @JayGadariya yes `contentTextStyle` is a property to change label style only!

Comment: @RobinManoli Due to a certain issue in sanckbar I prefer [flushbar 1.9.1](https://pub.dev/packages/flushbar). It is more customizable.

Comment: @RobinManoli Hi I face, the same issue. Can you please provide me with some information how to set default font for `flatButton`

Answer (score -1):

You can customize the Snackbar's action font family by changing the **button** theme in the app's global theme. This is because the Snackbar's action is considered as a button. For example, set:

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    textTheme: TextTheme(
       button: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
    ),
  ),
  home: const MyHomePage(title: appName),
);
```

The actions in Snackbars will be affected as desired if you follow the instructions on https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts for implementing custom fonts.