# Toast Message Style Change in flutter? Only Toast Message not Snackbar Other No Widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Currently, I'm trying to develop an app. and I don't know how to change the Toast font..
Toast Message Text to Change Font-Family?

Comment: more info needed to actually help you.

Comment: Normal Basic Toast Like, (ex. using library fluttertoast to output widget ) to same widget in toast Message Text to Change Font-Family?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to change the font of a snackbar?

The best way would be to change the snackBarTheme to set the font globally for all snackbars:

```
 runApp(MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      snackBarTheme: SnackBarThemeData(contentTextStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: "montserrat")),
    ),
...
```

Reference:

[How to create Toast in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948168/how-to-create-toast-in-flutter)

[flutter: set font of SnackbarAction label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59102711/flutter-set-font-of-snackbaraction-label)